# glutWarpPointer makes multiple calls to the glutPassiveMotionFunc call back

Tags: c++, graphics, 3d, glut

I'm implementing a FPS style mouse look to "fly" around my scene.

I've got the right camera rotation and everything, my only problem is that when I try to warp the mouse to the middle of the screen, it performs multiple calls to the glutPassiveMotionFunc call back. So instead of teleporting the mouse, its moving it there over a few movements. These movements get processed and move the camera back to the original position.

How do I check that the mouse was actually moved and it was not triggered by the glutWarpPointer function.

I've tried to not process a movements if the pointer is in the middle of the screen but this doesn't help.

I want my program to run on Linux and Windows so I cannot use OS specific functions.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't call this a great solution, but it should work:

```
bool isWarpingPointer = false;

void MyPassiveMovementCallback()
{
    if (isWarpingPointer)
    {
        return;
    }

    //proceed normally
}

//elsewhere
isWarpingPointer = true;
glutWarpPointer();
isWarpingPointer = false;
```

Comment: Is FreeGLUT guaranteed to call the mouse callback function within the call to `glutWarpPointer`?

Comment: It doesn't seem to call the mouse callback from within the glutWarpPointer call. To make this hack work you'd have to ignore the next callback assuming it's caused by the glutWarpPointer and set the isWarpingPointer to false. Not ideal but does roughly work.